# (void)^(void) in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this ^ syntax mean in Objective-C ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499186/what-does-this-syntax-mean-in-objective-c)

hai folks,
         can any one please explain what is this. i don't know what kind of data to pass for this argument. following is the method

```
- (BOOL)setKeepAliveTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout handler:(void(^)(void))keepAliveHandler
```

please explain whether it means void pointer or else.

plz explain me or give me any useful url's for this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pascal, nartin clayton: Agree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a [Block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html), an extension to the C language coined by Apple and available since OS X 10.6 and iOS 4.0.