# Objective-C signal void (^)(void), what does it mean?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this ^ syntax mean in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499186/what-does-this-syntax-mean-in-objective-c)

I found the declaration of function addOperationWithBlock as following:

```
- (void)addOperationWithBlock:(void (^)(void))block NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

So, what does `(void (^)(void))block` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It declares a method named "-addOperationWithBlock:", which takes one parameter, which is a pointer to a block that has no parameters and returns nothing.

The NS_AVAILABLE macro tells the compiler that this method is only available in Mac OS 10.6 or later, or iOS 4.0 or later.