# What is the meaning of (^) sign in Objective C method

Tags: ios, objective-c

In an app i found a function - `(void)performExitAnimationWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL))block`.
What is the purpose of using (^). I want to know the meaning of full function in details.

Comment: this is Objective C block. read the apple doc here: [Working with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Comment: Here is a great blog post explaining why: http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/08/21/objective-c-blocks-syntax/

Comment: It looks like the issue right over over:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077562/meaning-of-symbol-in-objective-c

Comment: And here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499186/what-does-this-syntax-mean-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3):

This sign **^** (caret sign) represent block operation. You can learn more about blocks [here in apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)