# block object needs further explaining

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, anonymous-function

I understand how block objects work - but I have not come across this type of block object,  Im not sure what the following code does:

```
 [localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            int i = 0;
            do {
                MKMapItem *mapItem = [response.mapItems objectAtIndex:i];
                [self.mapItems addObject:mapItem];
                i++;
            } while (i < response.mapItems.count);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Address Found" object:self];
        } else {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Not Found" object:self];
        }
    }];
}
```

I would be great if someone could provide an explanation on what is going on here.

Comment: If you "understand how block objects work" then what exactly do you not understand here?

Answer (score 1):

The function after the caret (^) is a "block".  [See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499186/what-does-this-syntax-mean-in-objective-c)

The localSearch object will invoke the block (anonymous function) defined below when it needs to (when it has completed).  This is like a delegate assigned to work off the result of the operation, but without requiring you to define a new function to receive the callback.  The calling class is the delegate (i.e. self refers to the caller in the function).

I added some comments for specific details.

```
   (MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
// If there is not an error
        if (!error) {
            int i = 0;
            do {
                MKMapItem *mapItem = [response.mapItems objectAtIndex:i];
// The map items found are added to a mapItems NSMutableArray (presumed) that is 
// owned by the original caller of this function.
                [self.mapItems addObject:mapItem];
                i++;
            } while (i < response.mapItems.count);
// Using the Observer design pattern here.  Some other object must register for the
// @"Address Found" message.  If any were found, it will be called.
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Address Found" object:self];
        } else {
// Using the notification center to announce "not found".  I am not sure if this is correct,
// since this would be the response if there was an error, and not found is not necessarily
// the same as an error occurring.
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Not Found" object:self];
        }
```

Was this helpful?

Is there a specific problem you were trying to address?

Comment: the part which is confusing is what is the caret notation here is doing: startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error)

Comment: Read the post referenced.  It goes into detail about the notation.  It weirded me out at first as well...I was very comfortable with delegates and such.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have on mind that there is two different technologies blocks and notifications.
Block **startWithCompletionHandler** is called when the search finished, after the data from search are processed and send by NSNotification.

You can subscribe to receive notifications anywhere in your app.

Read more about
[NSNotification Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Blocks in ObjC are simply a callback function.

In the function above, localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler, the callback accepts two parameters: response and error.

When this block is called, when a search is complete, the code above runs through all they key/value pairs in 'response', and adds them to a local key/value map called self.mapItems.

After that it posts a notification through NSNotificationCenter with "Address Found".

If error is not NULL, that is, a pointer to NSError has been provided, it will just send an error notification message instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This block will be run after the method is finished (`startWithCompletionHandler:`)
It checks if there is no error and it will enumerate `response.mapItems` array by `do while` loop. It gets every `MKMapItem` object and add it to `self.mapItems` array. After all array is done a notification (Address Found) will be post so every object which subscribe it will be notify. If there is an error an notification (Not Found) will be post.