# Separate function for UIView animateWithDuration animations and completion parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, animation, animatewithduration

I am working with animations in iOS7 with objective-c. I am trying to use the animateWithDuration function which has the following definition:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) animations:^(void)animations completion:^(BOOL finished)completion]
```

I can use this just fine, but it makes my code overly long because I have to put my animation and completion functions all in this declaration. I would like to create a separate function and pass it into the animation function call.

Specifically I would like to be able to have a separate completion function to use with multiple animations, which would also require the ability to pass it the parameter of a the specific view's id.

Could someone explain how to set up a function that can be passed into the animate function, and also what the '^' in the ^(void) and ^(BOOL) means?

Thanks

Comment: Learn about Objective-C blocks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499186/what-does-this-syntax-mean-in-objective-c Blocks is what ^ means.

Comment: As "rmaddy" already mentioned, get in and learn block programming.  It's an essential part of Objective-c programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `^` indicates [a block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) (note that these are not *functions*).  You can certainly do what you want.  You would use:

`returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes) = ^returnType(parameters) {...};`

So your code would look something like this:

```
void (^animations)() = ^{
    // Do some animations.
};

void (^completion)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL finished){
    // Complete.
};

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:animations completion:completion];
```

FYI, this is a great reference for block syntax: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate things. Just use this method instead:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    // your animations
}];
```

Next time you come across a block you have no use for, just put `nil` in the block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         // your animations
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

The `^` means that you are declaring a block in Objective-C.

If you just want to make your method call shorter, you can do this:

```
void (^myCompletionBlock)(BOOL finished) = ^void(BOOL finished) {
    // What you want to do on completion
};

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     // your animations
                 }
                 completion:myCompletionBlock];
```